# Which work item should a changeset be associated with?

Tags: tfs

Is it preferrable to associate your changeset with the task that described the work to be done in the changeset, or should it be associated with the User Story/Bug/Requirement that called for the change. To me, I would think it would be the task, since the task will roll up to the parent work item that created the task. However, I'm being told to associate the changeset with the parent work item. If I do that, I won't be able to determine which code was affected by my task. I'm told that I have to do it against the parent work item for some reporting reason or testing requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associating it with the Task will still give you traceability back to the User Story/Bug.  Ultimately it will result in richer more granular data in your data warehouse.  It is still possible to report on the data, and if somebody wanted the report to show User Stories/Bugs and associated changesets all the data is there to do this (find all child works items, and all changesets associated with child work items), it just may require slightly more work on behalf of the report designer.

Personally I favor capturing the richer information by associating it with the Task if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Do both. There's nothing stopping you from associating a check in with multiple work items, the real question is what do you intend to do with the traceability information.

As @Dylan Smith mentioned, tracking at the lower level improves the granularity of the information, and if you were only going to choose one work item to associate to, then that would be my choice as well.